How can I implement automatic reconnection in a decentralized WebRTC network without user interaction?
I'm developing a Flutter application and considering using WebRTC for syncing data in a completely decentralized environment, involving STUN and TURN servers. Although I'm relatively new to WebRTC,  I've managed some tests across different networked browsers. The initial connections are established successfully, allowing message exchanges, but these connections often drop after a while for various reasons.
I aim to implement a feature where, after any kind of network interruption (e.g., a peer going offline and then coming back online), the application can automatically reconnect to another peer without any user intervention, similar to a renegotiation process.
Question:
How can I implement automatic reconnection in a decentralized WebRTC network without user interaction after a disconnection?
